# TSQLUnit for SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unit-testing, sql-server-2000, tsqlunit

I need a testing framework for SQL Server 2000 (yeah, I know).

I would ideally use tSQLt with Red Gate Test but it does not work on SQL 2000 because it requires CLR (among other issues).

A lot of the info out there suggests [TSQLUnit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tsqlunit/) is (was?) supported for SQL Server 2000 but the versions on sourceforge all include non-supported syntax.

Specifically, the helper proc `tsu_FakeTable` includes this local variable:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX);
```

and I'm concerned `VARCHAR(8000)` is a gotcha waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, the procedure `tsu_FakeTable` is part of a suite of helper functions rather than being part of TSQLUnit itself.

Comment: Which means you *can* use TSQLUnit with SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Ah, how refreshing to know! I was about to go with the saying ‘Silence gives consent’, but it is really good of you to come back and silence any doubt. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you willing to consider an alternative framework? For example [DbFit](http://gojko.net/fitnesse/dbfit/) (now maintained as part of the [fitSharp](http://fitsharp.github.com/) project), which supports SQL 2000.

Comment: Yes I'm considering alternatives but I need to KISS and I'm not using FitNesse.